Handling which key was invalidated by mutation
I need to do some side effects on tag invalidation. In my case this is informing other tabs that some data need to be refetched. Simple way is using "onQueryStarted" to fire event to other tabs but this will require to change all mutations so i am looking for a more general solution (on middleware level or smth).
Im trying to handle action within redux middleware but action body does not contain any information about which tags should be invalidated by mutation
